# How to configure a kubernetes pod, to create a pod from with a pod?

Tags: python, kubernetes, gcloud

I have a work requirement where I needed to create a Kubernetes Pod(say child pod) from with in a pod(sat Master pod) in the same cluster.

So far I was able to create a child pod from master pod.

Problem, where I wanted help is the setup for `gcloud` and `kubernetes`. To make my pod create these child pods, I had to install these two & configure them with same credentials as I have in my local system.

Issues at hand

1. (what is the best way/standard way)How to configure - gcloud & kubernetes in this scenario?
2. Is there any other way I dont have to install gcloud and kubernetes in the pod?

Comment: I'm wondering in what scenario you want to have entire kubernetes in 1 pod.

Comment: sorry for confusion, I wanted to create a neighbouring pod. Not like creating pod with in pod but create a pod from pod. Hope this is clear.Reason is simple. I pay for the resources I use.

Comment: Question:  Do you want to clone a pod, or do you want to run the `gcloud` and `kubectl` commands inside a pod to create a totally different pod?